# How does the .net core 5 Web Api session work with Angular?

Tags: angular, session, asp.net-core-webapi

I have 2 web api, one is set the session when angular call HTTP get method, and want to retrieve the session value in HTTP post method.
I have done some research need to setup session in startup.cs, below is my startup code:

```
services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
                options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
                options.Cookie.Name = "captchaImageKey";
                //options.Cookie.SameSite = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
            });

services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(name: MyAllowSpecificOrigins, builder =>
                {
                    // Allow multiple methods  
                    builder.WithMethods("GET", "POST")
                      .WithHeaders(
                        HeaderNames.Accept,
                        HeaderNames.ContentType,
                        HeaderNames.Authorization)
                      .AllowCredentials()
                      .SetIsOriginAllowed(origin =>
                      {
                          if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(origin)) return false;
                          // Only add this to allow testing with localhost, remove this line in production!  
                          if (origin.ToLower().StartsWith("http://localhost")) return true;
                          // Insert your production domain here.  
                          if (origin.ToLower().StartsWith("https://dev.mydomain.com")) return true;
                          return false;
                      });
                });

            });
```

When I call post method to get the session value, the session id is always different, and unable to retrieve the session value which I have called before.

```
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("getCaptchaImage")]
        public IActionResult GetCaptchaImage()
        {
            int width = 150;
            int height = 58;
            var captchaCode = Captcha.GenerateCaptchaCode();
            var result = Captcha.GenerateCaptchaImage(width, height, captchaCode);

            HttpContext.Session.Set("CaptchaCode", Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(result.CaptchaCode));

            Stream s = new MemoryStream(result.CaptchaByteData);
            return new FileStreamResult(s, "image/png");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> SubmitAsync(ResetPasswordVM resetPassword)
        {
                string sessionID = HttpContext.Session.Id;
                HttpContext.Session.TryGetValue("CaptchaCode", out byte[] VALUE_BYTES);
                var value = VALUE_BYTES == null ? "" : Encoding.ASCII.GetString(VALUE_BYTES);
        }
```

My angular web app cookies is always empty.

Is anyone can help on this?
Thanks!

Comment: ASP.NET Core maintains session state by providing a cookie to the client that contains a session ID, which is sent to the app with each request. The app uses the session ID to fetch the session data. In a typical SPA you are making stateless API calls though that will not contain cookies. So, it's generally discouraged to rely on state/sessions in REST APIs. You could consider using the [In-memory caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to store the data.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried to use the In-Memory-Caching, i open 2 same web applications on the browser, and try to store and retrieve the data in cache memory, however, the value which i store under web app 1 is overwritten by web app 2 value. I would like to know for the case, is the cache value will shared among different client request?